# CorsRegistry configuration seems to have no effect in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cors, spring-security-oauth2

The addCorsMappings functionality doesn't work for me in spring.
I have just :

```
public void addCorsMapping(CorsRegistry registry){ 
    registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("/**"); 
}
```

This is declared in my ServletConfig.java.

The error on the client is :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=backoffice&state=xyz&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.".
```

Can anyone tell me why and how to debug this?

Answer (score 2):

Should be:

```
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry){ 
    registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*"); 
}
```